# How to implement `&&` (overlap) operator of postgres in DynamoDB?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

How to implement [`&&` (overlap) operator of postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-array.html#:%7E:text=%26t%26,t) in DynamoDB?

Like postgres behaves -

```sql
select array[1, 2, 3] && array[2, 3];
-> true

select array[1, 2, 3] && array[3, 4];
-> true

select array[1, 2, 3] && array[4, 5];
-> false
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't - pull the 2 array values down and assert this within code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to achieve the above scenario. It may not be a good solution so open to your opinions and answers.

I used `contains` with `or` of DynamoDB to reach the desired results as follows.

field -> #arrayOfElements 
values -> :elementToMatch (String)

```sql
contains(#arrayOfElements, :elementToMatch1) or contains(#arrayOfElements, :elementToMatch2)
```

Ex-

```sql
-- select array[1, 2, 3] && array[2, 3];
contains([1, 2, 3], 2) or contains([1, 2, 3], 3) -- raw example query
```